# addSnapshotListener, get, update, etc. in onActivityCreated are called several times (when the user rotates the screen for example)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-lifecycle

In `Fragment` and in `Dialogs` I have put some code relative to CRUD operation on my Firestore database. These operations are, *e.g.*, `addSnapshotListener` , `get`, `update` , `WriteBatches` , ...

The problem is that the user can rotates the screen, leading to a re-execution of those CRUD operations, which are not free - I have the Firebase SPARK Plan so it's actually free but if the limit is reached, no further CRUD operation will be done until the month ends or something like that.

So my question is: should I put these CRUD operations in another callback than `onActivityCreated` (if yes: how could I put the UI code that I've written in the CRUD operations' `onComplete` callback, which must be put in `onActivityCreated`?)? Or: is there another solution, for example a cache system?

Comment: I personally use the recent Android Arch Components to make my data lifecycle-aware, as I explain in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532749/5861618)

Comment: Thank you, you should write an answer so that I'll be able to upvote it :). However, I won't use any other API to solve this "problem".